# Internet Explorer compatibility disaster

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm in a completely disastrous situation right now.

According to Google Analytics, 96% of the users to my site are on Chrome & Firefox. However, we have one very important client coming on board at the beginning of next week ... and their entire organization will be using Internet Explorer.

I need some way of quickly making the core features of my site IE compatible. I can pay a consulting company if that is necessary, but I don't know the first thing about making my site IE compatible - I don't know the IE development tools and I don't know the first thing as to why IE doesn't render things properly.

What's the best way to go about solving my problem? I don't even see a firebug / inspect element equivalent for IE. I only will worry about IE 9 for now - this company is on the latest IE for sure.

Let me know, I'm totally panicked!

Comment: Hit F12 and see what happens...

Comment: Press `F12` and you get better developer tools than firebug. Also what's wrong, what doesn't work? Do you use HTML5, then you need to use HTML5shiv. Is your site W3C valid?

Comment: +1 for the question title, makes justice to the cancer of the internet that is Internet Explorer (ex-web designer here). Sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: I only remember there are a lot of discrepancies regarding layout (that is, wrong implementation of the CSS standards mainly) between IE and the 'decent' browsers. First step is to view your website in various versions of IE. You can find standalone installers of most versions, so you don't need multie machines (but you might want to test WinXP, Vista, 7...)

Comment: IE 9 has relatively solid standards adherence. IE 8 isn't bad either. It's 7 and earlier that *really* pisses front-end developers off. You should be fine.

Comment: I'm testing on IE9 on Windows 7. The site looks great on most versions of Firefox & Chrome ... it is not even usable on IE. Its incredibly frustrating, because I don't think there is some magic "IE compatibility" tool that will tell me what major adjustments I need to make.

Comment: "it is not even usable on IE." You need to provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my suggestion.

1. [IE tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is a great tool to test your site across all IE
   versions.
2. Consider using specific tags target IE. Like:

   ```
   <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
   ```
3. Consider using [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) if your site uses HTML5 or CSS3.
4. If your site uses placeholder in forms, IE doesnt sopport it. So consider using something like [IE placeholder polyfill](https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill).
5. press F12 for developer tool.
6. IE has a different [box model](http://css-tricks.com/482-ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/).
7. Here is an article that discusses about [how IE handles various CSS properties](http://thescube.com/blog/2009/10/20/ie6-vs-ie7-vs-ie8-css-property/).
8. Convince your client not to use IE.(kidding..)

I know this list will keep on and on. May be ask another question when you fall in specific problem. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your site is valid HTML/CSS/JS and you don't use any browser-specific extensions, you should be good to go.

F12 will give you a full set of Developer Tools which can be very useful in finding and fixing stuff, so go ahead and use that. If you have any specific problems, I can certainly help you out with them.

Comment: Kolink, CSS & JS, I think we are fine on. I'd really prefer not to share the URL of my site here - is there a messaging or chat function on stackoverflow? I would great appreciate it if you could take a quick look at my site and tell me how to get started. My email address is ringoblancke@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

If I were in your position I wouldn't modify the existing, working website page, I would duplicate it, make the changes to get it working in Internet Explorer and then make your website detect the browser they are using and load the appropriate working page. Considering you need to make these changes so soon, you don't want to risk changing something which messes up how the site is displayed in Firefox and Chrome.